# How to do a nested renamer in pandas in groupby function

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to do like this

```
df_temp = df.groupby(['_SubjectId', 'QuestionTypeId'], as_index=True)['QuestionTypeId'].count()
```

Here Subject have 10 different values and Question type has 5 and i want to know how many   Questions are there of each QuestionType and Subject, i am able to do it with it but i also want to give a name to the count returned

I am doing it like this

```
df_temp = df.groupby(['_SubjectId', 'QuestionTypeId'], as_index=True).agg({'QuestionTypeId': {'count': 'count'}})
```

But it is giving me nested renaming error , so please suggest an alternative way of achieving the result i needed, i have gone through other answers but it is not helping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use names aggreagtion - it means for column `QuestionTypeId` use aggragation `count` and assign to column `new`:

```
df_temp = (df.groupby(['_SubjectId', 'QuestionTypeId'], as_index=True)
             .agg(new=('QuestionTypeId': 'count')))
```

Comment: it worked just instead of colon it would be a , as we need to give a tuple